# Dockerized Celery deployment without force KILL workers (ECS | Beanstalk multi container)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, django-celery, amazon-ecs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a `Dockerrun.aws.json` file which deploys celery container on EC2 instances using Beanstalk multi-container.

On every deployment, by default Beanstalk or the ECS agent kills the existing celery container on all the instances and then creates a new celery container. This kills the celery tasks immaturely which is creating issues since the tasks are unable to reach completion.

The celery container has `supervisord` which actually monitors the celery process and bring it up whenever it goes down.

Can someone suggest on how we can kill the celery containers/processes gracefully by allowing them to complete the tasks which they have already consumed from SQS?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a task you can use to put the workers in idle before you deploy.

Basically, create a task basically:

- sends you a notification confirming it is ready to be killed
- properly deletes SQS message to ensure it does not get re-executed in the future.
- enters an infinite loop to prevent other tasks from executing on the given task. More than an infinite loop, I would suggest going to sleep for 30min or whatever you want to use as a window for deployment ( just in case the deployment fails and you want to be able to recover )

Your deployment would then be:

- Post SQS to put workers to sleep
- Deploy normally. When the new worker comes alive, it will automatically begin to process new tasks.